# Are any college stamps required on the letters of recommendation for masters abroad?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter

My head of the department is not providing me any department stamp on the letter of recommendation stating that the letter head is enough and with it stamps are not used. I have no idea if it's correct or not but I didn't want to take chances with my LOR.  Thus, my main doubt is regarding this. Do I require any stamp of the department on the letter of recommendation for masters, to verify it's authenticity?

Comment: "_I have noticed several LORs and all have official stamps_" How did you notice them?

Comment: I have never seen an LOR with any kind of "official stamp". Transcripts are sometimes documented more officially.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not be worried. You professor is right. You do not need stamps or markers or a public notary's endorsement.

I am in academia in the US and if we felt the need to verify a recommendation letter, we would just (1) look up the writer and (2) contact the writer directly. Mostly, receiving a letter from an academic email address containing a pdf with an institutional letter head establishes prima facie credentials.

When I write invitation letters for conferences so that participants can get a visa for the US, I do exactly that: an email with institutional letterhead emailed as a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I very often write recommendations for European Universities, especially Germany and the Netherlands, and **no, no kind of stamps are required**, only proper letterhead and contact information.

Note that in most systems the student does not see the recommendation letter. The recommender usually sends the recommendation directly via email or by a electronic system to the receiving institution.

For verification of authenticity, there are other methods if required, such as directly contacting the letter writer, or requiring specific measures like using institutional emails (no free email accounts are accepted). This is why the student is not directly part of this process in most cases.

Comment: But what if students  have to upload the recommendation letters themselves while applying?